# Creating a Stack GUI Program

Tags: java, user-interface, stack

So I am creating a GUI Java program where by the user can enter a number into a text field and it is pushed to a stack which is displayed somewhere on the frame.

Currently I have the GUI all setup, its just the pushing, popping and peeking the stack I am struggling with.

I am aware of how a stack works (the whole last in, first out concept) however I just cannot get my head around how to apply this concept to a text field and a button!

My knowledge of Java GUI is quite poor so I would much appreciate some guidance as all the guides I have read have not helped me apply any of this to my problem! This is the current code, I must explain that the tabbedpane is being used to expand on the program further in future, however it is just the Stack tab that I am currently working on.

This is what I have so far, I have removed the imports from the top of the code just to tidy things up in this post, however they can be added again if required:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Stack;

public abstract class DefaultFrame implements ActionListener {

public static Stack<Integer> stack;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Data Container");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1080, 720);

    JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane();
    StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
    pane.addTab("Stack", stackPanel);
    stackPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JTextPane stacktext = new JTextPane();
    stacktext.setText(
            "A Stack in Java is a container for variables, similar to an Array. It could be visualised as a stack of plates or books, where you would need to remove plates in order to access plates that are further down the stack. A Stack uses these keywords; Push, Pop and Peek.\r\n\r\nPush: Pushes another variable to the top of the stack.\r\nPop: Removes the top variable from the stack.\r\nPeek: Returns the variable at the top of the stack");
    stackPanel.add(stacktext, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JPanel function = new JPanel();
    stackPanel.add(function, BorderLayout.WEST);
    function.setSize(540, 980);

    JTextField txtinput = new JTextField();
    function.add(txtinput);
    txtinput.setColumns(10);
    String number = txtinput.getText();


    JButton btnPush = new JButton("Push");
    function.add(btnPush);
    btnPush.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            push();
        }

        private void push() {

            int input = Integer.parseInt(number);
            stack.push(input);

        }
    });

    JButton btnPop = new JButton("Pop");
    function.add(btnPop);

    JButton btnPeek = new JButton("Peek");
    function.add(btnPeek);

    JPanel display = new JPanel();
    stackPanel.add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pane.addTab("Queue", new QueuePanel());
    pane.addTab("Set", new SetPanel());
    pane.addTab("Tree", new TreePanel());
    pane.addTab("List", new ListPanel());
    pane.addTab("Stack", new StackPanel());

    frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: You have to add a `ActionListener` to the buttons. In this `ActionListener`s you have to add your logic.

Comment: As @Jérôme has said, implement `onClick` functions for the push, pop and peek buttons. So, whenever these buttons are clicked, numbers (validation must be done) from textbox are added into your stack and update the view accordingly.

Comment: Basically what I've tried using an ActionListener is storing the input from the user using .getText() in a string called input, however where I implement my logic for the Push button the compliler can't access input (I assume this is the case because the auto fix options are to create a String). So I can't just use stack.push(input) because as I say I don't think it can access the string. Maybe I have defined it in the wrong place.

Comment: The `stack.push(input)` has to be in the `ActionListener`

Comment: Think I have it close to somewhere being right. However, the stack.push(input) has an error message telling me I need to change the String called input to an Integer. When I do this I get an error message on the .getText() saying cannot parse from string to integer.

Comment: You have defined `Stack<Integer> stack` so you have to add `Integer` to the stack. You can parse the input by using `Integer.parseInt(input)` or change to `Stack<String>stack`

Comment: Edited my code however I get this error message when I run the program despite no errors displaying on the code:    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at DefaultFrame.main(DefaultFrame.java:34)

Comment: The `getText()`-method gives you an empty String. `Integer.parseInt` cant handle an empty `String`. Look [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Comment: So do I need to parse the input when pushing to the stack?

Comment: Just changed my code so the .parseInt is the line above the push to stack and the program opens however I get a massive error message when I enter a number and click the Push button. Can't even fit the error message in this comments box!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to initialize your `stack`.

```
public static Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();//initialize stack
```

then you have to add an `ActionListener` and put the wanted behaviour in it. So for the Push-button it will look like

```
JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea(20, 1);//To display pushed values
jTextArea.setEditable(false);

JButton btnPush = new JButton("Push");
function.add(btnPush);
btnPush.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String input = txtinput.getText();//first get the input
        if (!input.isEmpty()){//check that inout is not empty
            stack.push(Integer.parseInt(input));//push on stack
            System.out.println("input = " + input);
            jTextArea.setText("");//clear TextArea
            stack.forEach(element -> jTextArea.append(element + System.lineSeparator()));//for every element in stack add (element + \n)
        }else{
            System.out.println("Input is empty");
        }
    }
});
```

For reuse of the `JTextArea`-update you should create an `ActionListener` like the following

```
JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea(20, 1);//To display pushed values
jTextArea.setEditable(false);

JButton btnPush = new JButton("Push");
JButton btnPop = new JButton("Pop");
JButton btnPeek = new JButton("Peek");
JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Reload stack");

ActionListener updateListener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jTextArea.setText("");//clear TextArea
        stack.forEach(x -> jTextArea.append(x + System.lineSeparator()));//for every element in stack add (element + \n)
    }
};
btnUpdate.addActionListener(updateListener);
btnPush.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String input = txtinput.getText();
        if (!input.isEmpty()) {
            stack.push(Integer.parseInt(input));
            System.out.println("input = " + input);                    
            updateListener.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(btnPush, 0, ""));//call the updateListener to refresh jTextArea
        } else {
            System.out.println("Input is empty");
        }

    }
});
function.add(btnPush);
function.add(btnPop);
function.add(btnPeek);

function.add(jTextArea);
function.add(btnUpdate);
```

Use the `updateListener.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(btnPush, 0, ""));` in your pop-action

To clearify:

```
stack.forEach(element -> jTextArea.append(element + System.lineSeparator()));
```

can also be written like:

```
for(Enumeration<Integer> elements = stack.elements();elements.hasMoreElements();){            
    jTextArea.append(elements.nextElement() + System.lineSeparator());
}
//or    
for(int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++) {
    jTextArea.append(stack.get(i) + System.lineSeparator());
}
//or    
for (Integer aStack : stack) {
    jTextArea.append(aStack + System.lineSeparator());
}
```

Comment: How could I display the stack and have it automatically update each time a new number is pushed using the Push button? What would be the best GUI element to display this in?

Comment: I would suggest a `JTextArea`. I updated my code. Please accept as answer if you like it ;-)

Comment: And please update youre code if you have a better solution than you posted

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you just briefly be able to explain what is happening in the line below clearing the textarea? The stack.forEach line? Thank you again!

Comment: The `stack.forEach(...)` iterates over every element in the stack. The notation i used is called lamda notation and can be used since java 8. In this notation `element` is the current element of the stack and after the `->` you can write what you want with the `element`.